# Google Buzz Button update Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-buzz

So, i have been looking for the answer, but all i find is news about how good/bad/and indifferent people are towards the google buzz button.  No programmatic way of doing what i need.  Basically i have a feed that updates every few seconds and there is a twitter, facebook, and buzz button associated with it.  The facebook and twitter are easy to tell the document to update the information.

```
function _UpdateSocialMedia(element) {
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(element.attr("id")));
    element.find('a.twitter-share-button').each(function() {
        var tweet_button = new twttr.TweetButton($(this).get(0));
        tweet_button.render();
    });
}
```

But how would i update the google buzz button, so that everytime something is added into the page via javascript, that i can tell the google button.js to update the button at a specific element???

Comment: BTW, i just found those on the internet, and they work, so i kept them. But i cannot find the google buzz button.render() or Google.parse function :)  (obviously i dont mean functions named with those exact names, but functions whose purpose is to fulfill my every wish and desire!!!).